# R function to convert numeric (23) to English ("twenty-three")

Tags: r

Is there an R function that will convert numeric values to their English representation? It would work like this:

```
> to.words(5)
[1] "five"
> to.words(23)
[1] "twenty-three"
```

Comment: If there isn't a ready made function, it looks like this should be pretty easy to follow and write in R: http://www.c.happycodings.com/Beginners_Lab_Assignments/code51.html

Comment: It indeed sounds like a fun project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's now the `english` package:

```
library(english)

english(5)
english(23)

## > english(23)
## [1] twenty three
## > english(23)
## [1] twenty three
```

Comment: The documentation suggests that this package is a wrapper on John Fox's original code, so it should behave the same. I think it's nice to have it in package form, and it looks like the author has added some nice convenience features. (I'm just using it for the first time now.)

Answer (score 6):

There has been an example function for small numbers given on *R-help* :

http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/Rhelp10/2008-March/155928.html

And there's another (which seems more complete) published by John Fox in the 5/1 volume of R news, starting page 51. The function itself is page 53 :

http://cran.r-project.org/doc/Rnews/Rnews_2005-1.pdf

Answer (score 4):

The number2words function you can find in the article "How Do You Spell That Number?" by John Fox in The Volume 5/1, May 2005 of RNews (you can download from [here](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/Rnews/Rnews_2005-1.pdf)) is what you are looking for.